# Table with date columns - conversion error with variables

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called [Tails] that looks like this.

```
Duration  January  February ....
1         0.8782   0.735
2         37.22    0.678
3         0.544    0.47347
```

What I need to do is lookup values for a given month depending on circumstances. So far I have (for example):

```
DECLARE @monthX Date = '04-01-2016'
Select [Duration],
iif(.....,datename(month,@monthX),....)
From [Tails]
```

This should be the equivalent of 
    SELECT [Duration], [APRIL] FROM [TAILS]

But my code results in a conversion error message. I've tried a few different ways to convert the variable to work like this after searching online for a solution and am getting nowhere.

Please can anyone advise? I am using SQL Server 2014.

Thank you so much

Comment: Since you are trying to get the column name, I think you need to use dynamic SQL and execute the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your query dynamically and then use [EXECUTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) to execute it :

```
DECLARE @monthX Datetime
DECLARE @monthS varchar(20)
SET @monthX = '04-01-2016'
SET @monthS = datename(month,@monthX)
DECLARE @SQL varchar(100)
SET @SQL = 'select [Duration], [' + @monthS + '] from [Tails];'
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not select columns like that, but you could construct a dynamic sql query and execute it with `sp_executesql` like so:

```
declare @monthX Date = '20160101';
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'Select [Duration], '+quotename(datename(month,@monthx))+' From [Tails];';

select @sql as sql;
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

The query executed for this example would be:

```
Select [Duration], [January] From [Tails];
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KBAS15857

Comment: Yup, you got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole column summed... Use this (minus the temp data for testing)

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = '2/28/17'
DECLARE @monthname VARCHAR(20)
SET @monthname = DATENAME(month, @date)
DECLARE @strSQL varchar(100)

CREATE TABLE #tempTable(duration int, january NUMERIC(28,12), february NUMERIC(28,12))

INSERT INTO #temptable(duration, january, february)
VALUES(1     ,    0.8782  ,0.735)
INSERT INTO #temptable(duration, january, february)
VALUES(2     ,    37.22  ,0.678)
INSERT INTO #temptable(duration, january, february)
VALUES(3     ,    0.544  ,0.47347)


SET @strSQL = 'select SUM(' + @monthname + ') from #tempTable;'
EXECUTE (@strSQL)


DROP TABLE #tempTable
```

Comment: Thank you very much